# How can I loop through this array and get first elements?

Tags: php

OK, pulling my hair out again today. I need to loop through this array to get the keys for the elements seen here as "Escalations, "Premium", "Standard", etc... so I can display them in a table.

I've tried this and all it gives me "abandoned", I can't figure out how to move up in the hierarchy.

```
foreach($calls as $call){
$results[ $call['queue_name'] ][ $call['type'] ] = $call['calls'];
$totalCalls += $call['calls'];
$typeTotals[ $call['type'] ] = isset( $typeTotals[ $call['type'] ]) ? $typeTotals[ $call['type'] ] + $call['calls'] : $call['calls'];
}
```

**HERE IS A var_dump:**

```
array(5) { 
["Escalations"]=> array(3) { 
    ["abandoned"]=> string(1) "2" 
    ["completed"]=> string(1) "3" 
    ["redirected"]=> string(1) "1" } 

["Premium"]=> array(3) { 
    ["abandoned"]=> string(1) "7" 
    ["completed"]=> string(2) "29" 
    ["redirected"]=> string(1) "6" } 

["Standard"]=> array(3) { 
    ["abandoned"]=> string(2) "14" 
    ["completed"]=> string(2) "41" 
    ["redirected"]=> string(2) "53" } 

["Wingate Queue"]=> array(2) { 
    ["abandoned"]=> string(1) "2" 
    ["completed"]=> string(1) "3" } 

["WorldMark"]=> array(3) { 
    ["abandoned"]=> string(2) "32" 
    ["completed"]=> string(3) "100" 
    ["redirected"]=> string(2) "82" } } 


array(5) { 
["Escalations"]=> array(3) { 
    ["abandoned"]=> string(1) "2" 
    ["completed"]=> string(1) "3" 
    ["redirected"]=> string(1) "1" } 

["Premium"]=> array(3) { 
    ["abandoned"]=> string(1) "7" 
    ["completed"]=> string(2) "29" 
    ["redirected"]=> string(1) "6" } 

["Standard"]=> array(3) { 
    ["abandoned"]=> string(2) "14" 
    ["completed"]=> string(2) "41" 
    ["redirected"]=> string(2) "53" } 

["Wingate Queue"]=> array(2) { 
    ["abandoned"]=> string(1) "2" 
    ["completed"]=> string(1) "3" } 

["WorldMark"]=> array(3) { 
    ["abandoned"]=> string(2) "32" 
    ["completed"]=> string(3) "100" 
    ["redirected"]=> string(2) "82" } } 


array(5) { 
["Escalations"]=> array(3) { 
    ["abandoned"]=> string(1) "2" 
    ["completed"]=> string(1) "3" 
    ["redirected"]=> string(1) "1" } 

["Premium"]=> array(3) { 
    ["abandoned"]=> string(1) "7" 
    ["completed"]=> string(2) "29" 
    ["redirected"]=> string(1) "6" } 

["Standard"]=> array(3) { 
    ["abandoned"]=> string(2) "14" 
    ["completed"]=> string(2) "41" 
    ["redirected"]=> string(2) "53" } 

["Wingate Queue"]=> array(2) { 
    ["abandoned"]=> string(1) "2" 
    ["completed"]=> string(1) "3" } 

["WorldMark"]=> array(3) { 
    ["abandoned"]=> string(2) "32" 
    ["completed"]=> string(3) "100" 
    ["redirected"]=> string(2) "82" } }


array(5) { 
["Escalations"]=> array(3) { 
    ["abandoned"]=> string(1) "2" 
    ["completed"]=> string(1) "3" 
    ["redirected"]=> string(1) "1" } 

["Premium"]=> array(3) { 
    ["abandoned"]=> string(1) "7" 
    ["completed"]=> string(2) "29" 
    ["redirected"]=> string(1) "6" } 

["Standard"]=> array(3) { 
    ["abandoned"]=> string(2) "14" 
    ["completed"]=> string(2) "41" 
    ["redirected"]=> string(2) "53" } 

["Wingate Queue"]=> array(2) { 
    ["abandoned"]=> string(1) "2" 
    ["completed"]=> string(1) "3" } 

["WorldMark"]=> array(3) { 
    ["abandoned"]=> string(2) "32" 
    ["completed"]=> string(3) "100" 
    ["redirected"]=> string(2) "82" } }


array(5) { 
["Escalations"]=> array(3) { 
    ["abandoned"]=> string(1) "2" 
    ["completed"]=> string(1) "3" 
    ["redirected"]=> string(1) "1" } 

["Premium"]=> array(3) { 
    ["abandoned"]=> string(1) "7" 
    ["completed"]=> string(2) "29" 
    ["redirected"]=> string(1) "6" } 

["Standard"]=> array(3) { 
    ["abandoned"]=> string(2) "14" 
    ["completed"]=> string(2) "41" 
    ["redirected"]=> string(2) "53" } 

["Wingate Queue"]=> array(2) { 
    ["abandoned"]=> string(1) "2" 
    ["completed"]=> string(1) "3" }

["WorldMark"]=> array(3) { 
    ["abandoned"]=> string(2) "32" 
    ["completed"]=> string(3) "100" 
    ["redirected"]=> string(2) "82" } } 


 foreach($results as $result){
$perAbandoned = $totalCalls != 0 ? round( ($result['abandoned'] / $totalCalls) * 100 ) : 0;
$perRedirected = $totalCalls != 0 ? round( ($result['redirected'] / $totalCalls) * 100) : 0;
$perAnswered = $totalCalls != 0 ? round( ($result['completed'] / $totalCalls) * 100 ) : 0;  


echo  "<tr>";
echo "<td>" . key($result) . "</td>";//key
echo "<td>" . $totalCalls . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $result['completed'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $perAnswered . "%</td>";
echo "<td>" . $result['abandoned'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $perAbandoned . "%</td>";
echo "<td>" . $result['redirected'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $perRedirected . "%</td>";
echo "<td>techs logged in</td>";
echo  "</tr>";
}
```

**The ARRAY:**

```
array(5) { 
["Escalations"]=> array(3) { 
    ["abandoned"]=> string(1) "2" 
    ["completed"]=> string(1) "3" 
    ["redirected"]=> string(1) "1" } 

["Premium"]=> array(3) { 
    ["abandoned"]=> string(1) "7" 
    ["completed"]=> string(2) "29" 
    ["redirected"]=> string(1) "6" } 

["Standard"]=> array(3) { 
    ["abandoned"]=> string(2) "14" 
    ["completed"]=> string(2) "41" 
    ["redirected"]=> string(2) "53" } 

["Wingate Queue"]=> array(2) { 
    ["abandoned"]=> string(1) "2" 
    ["completed"]=> string(1) "3" } 

["WorldMark"]=> array(3) { 
    ["abandoned"]=> string(2) "32" 
    ["completed"]=> string(3) "100" 
    ["redirected"]=> string(2) "82" } }
```

Comment: are you looking for **foreach ($values as $key => value) {}**?

Comment: I'm looking to put "Escalations" etc into the table where it says key($result).

Comment: +1 for beeing person 1 of 1000 properly concatenating variables and strings

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're looking for this syntax:

```
foreach($results as $header => $result) {

   echo "<td>" . $header . "</td>";//key

}
```

Hope you control where the key name is coming from, as this is obviously vulnerable to XSS problems.

Comment: This makes no sense - what does XSS have to do with anything the OP posted, and how does switching to key=>value syntax prevent XSS as opposed to using key() function? I agree this is simpler, looks nicer, but it has nothing to do with XSS

Comment: this works well on it's own but it doesn't put the element in the table where I need it.

Comment: Solution: foreach($results as $header => $result){
 // To calculate precentages
 $perAbandoned = $totalCalls != 0 ? round( ($result['abandoned'] / $totalCalls) * 100 ) : 0;
 $perRedirected = $totalCalls != 0 ? round( ($result['redirected'] / $totalCalls) * 100) : 0;
 $perAnswered = $totalCalls != 0 ? round( ($result['completed'] / $totalCalls) * 100 ) : 0; 
 
 
 echo  "<tr>";
 echo "<td>" . $header. "</td>";//key
 ...
 }

Comment: @Jessica: OP had `key($result)`, which was wrong. Even `key($results)` would have been wrong as foreach loops in PHP create a copy of the array, and use a different array position than the one `key` would use. The XSS comment was unrelated to the OP's question, but I felt it was relevant to add in case OP missed it and the contents of the `$results` array came from for example a database or otherwise from the user. Makes sense?

Answer (score 1):

```
$types = ['abandoned', 'completed', 'redirected'];
foreach($results as $key=>$result){
   echo '<tr><td>'.$key.'</td><td>'.$totalCalls.'</td>';
   foreach($types AS $type){
      echo '<td>'.$result[$type].'</td><td>';
      echo $totalCalls != 0 ? round( ($result[$type] / $totalCalls) * 100 ) : 0;
      echo '%</td>';
   }
   echo '</tr>';
 }
```

Don't see anything wrong with your code but it's way longer and messier than need be.

Edit: Actually it sounds like you're looping through the second dimension of your array, where is the code before your existing foreach?

Comment: Do a var_dump($result); right inside your foreach. What does $result actually contain?

Comment: Looks fine to me, I don't see how your code can cause the problem you described.

Answer (score 0):

i suggest add a counter if you want to do something about the 2nd until the last
or stop the foreach loop after the 1st value if you dont have something to do with the
2nd until the last

```
foreach($results as $value) 
{

$counter=1;
if($counter > 1)
{
//do what you want on the 2nd until the end value
}else
{
echo "this is the 1st value";
$first=$value; //or store it
}

}
```